# How to create Windows Server Failover Cluster using Terraform

Tags: sql, azure, powershell, terraform

Hoping someone is able to assist with being able to create / automate a Windows Server Failover Cluster, on Windows Server 2019 DataCenter Edition VM/s (without SQL installed, and not on SQL Managed Instances) using Terraform, in Azure.

There does not appear to be a way to have this process automated. All instructions are either to create WSFC manually in Windows (add Features, format disks etc etc), or using PowerShell. I'm happy with PowerShell, but have been unable to build one script that can create the cluster that can be injected using Terraform Custom Script Extension. I have got an unattended Azure DevOps pipeline deploying the Windows 2019 VMs (and disks etc), adding them to the corporate domain, but just unable to create the WSFC, since creating the cluster requires domain credentials, and yet the pipeline runs with SYSTEM credentials, and Microsoft prohibits impersonating a domain user from a script running as SYSTEM account.

Note1:- SQL will be installed after the WSFC exists (using a Terraform CSE to run a PowerShell script)

Note2:- this is not on SQL Managed Instances. Purely IaaS VMs

Any assistance/guidance would be appreciated. Thank you

(Using: Terraform >=1.1.0, AzureRM Provider >=3.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

> The `azurerm_sql_failover_group` resource is deprecated in version 3.0 of the AzureRM provider and will be removed in version 4.0. Please use the [`azurerm_mssql_failover_group`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/mssql_failover_group) resource instead.

- Here is the Sample code of SQL Fail over group using Terraform.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_sql_server" "primary" {
  name                         = "sql-primary"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                     = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "sqladmin"
  administrator_login_password = "pa$$w0rd"
}

resource "azurerm_sql_server" "secondary" {
  name                         = "sql-secondary"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                     = "northeurope"
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "sqladmin"
  administrator_login_password = "pa$$w0rd"
}

resource "azurerm_sql_database" "db1" {
  name                = "db1"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_sql_server.primary.resource_group_name
  location            = azurerm_sql_server.primary.location
  server_name         = azurerm_sql_server.primary.name
}

resource "azurerm_sql_failover_group" "example" {
  name                = "example-failover-group"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_sql_server.primary.resource_group_name
  server_name         = azurerm_sql_server.primary.name
  databases           = [azurerm_sql_database.db1.id]
  partner_servers {
    id = azurerm_sql_server.secondary.id
  }

  read_write_endpoint_failover_policy {
    mode          = "Automatic"
    grace_minutes = 60
  }
}
```

- You can go through this [reference](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/sql_failover_group) for complete information.